# How to loop same sql query over different database instances and append data in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I have this `code` which establishes connection the DB and extracts data and stores to dataframe

**Current Code**

```
CONN_INFO = {'host': host,'port': port,'user': user,'psw': password,'service': service,}
CONN_STR = '{user}/{psw}@{host}:{port}/{service}'.format(**CONN_INFO)
connection=cx_Oracle.connect(CONN_STR)
cursor=connection.cursor()
cur.execute("""SELECT risk_level_01, risk_level_02, risk_type_code FROM public.md_risk_code""")

data=cur.fetchall()
columns = [column[0] for column in cur.description]
dfaws = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=columns)
```

Now I have scenario where I have execute the `sql`from 3 different databases and append the data from the 3 dbs. How can this done using loop concept.

I have the host as `host1,host2,host3`

I have the port as `port1,port2,port3`

I have the psw as `password1,password2,password3`

I have the service as `service1,service2,service3`

How can this can be run in a loop and extracted and stored into a dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a list of connection info dictionaries and loop through them. Using each connection info establish a connection to the database and extract the the data you want and append it to a dataframe that you will create locally.

The pseudocode will be:

```
CONN_INFOS = [{"host":host1,.....}, {"host":host2,.....}, ....]
df = pd.Dataframe() #Intialize a dataframe
for CONN_INFO in CONN_INFOS:
   CONN_STR = '{user}/{psw}@{host}:{port}/{service}'.format(**CONN_INFO)
   connection=cx_Oracle.connect(CONN_STR)
   cursor=connection.cursor()
   cur.execute("""SELECT risk_level_01, risk_level_02, risk_type_code FROM public.md_risk_code""")
   data=cur.fetchall()
   #append data to dataframe
   #close each connection after used
```